# Trouble with evaluating the limit of a function

Tags: limits

We have the following function:

$\mu_n(p)=\frac{1}{2}(n-1)!p^n$, where $n\geq 3$ and $0 \leq p \leq 1$.

Now, we want to find lim$\mu_n(\frac{c}{n})$ as n goes to infinity. where $c$ is a constant. Clearly, $c \geq 0$ and $n \geq c$. Moreover, we observe that $\frac{1}{2}(n-1)!$ goes to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity and $(\frac{c}{n})^n$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Thus, we have an indeterminate form. I tried to use the L'Hopital's (after conversion) but it doesn't seem to work in this case. I have also put that function on a computer, to get a better idea where I might be going with this and it looks like for some (small) $c$'s the limit goes to $0$ and then for bigger $c$'s it goes to infinity, which I don't really understand. How can we deal with this analytically? In the question, there is also a hint that  Stirling’s approximation may be useful. I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: consider the *series*
$$\sum(n−1)!{\frac{c^n}{n^n}}$$
and apply the *quotient* test. If the series is convergent, $(n−1)!{\frac{c^n}{n^n}}\to 0$.

Comment: Ohh, ok. So we get that the limit of $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$, where $a_n$ is the sequence inside the series above, is equal to $0$<$1$ so by the quotient test it is (absolutely) convergent and hence the sequence $a_n$ converges to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I just realized that I made a mistake. The limit of $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ is given by $\frac{c}{e}$. Is that correct?

Comment: Assuming that it is correct and then using the quotient test we could say that $(n-1)!\frac{c^n}{n^n} \to 0$ when $c<e$. But how can we then deal with the cases when $c \geq e$?

Comment: @amator2357, if $c > e$ the general term $\to\infty$.

Comment: what do you mean by general term? $(n-1)!\frac{c^n}{n^n}$?

Comment: @amator2357, yes.

Comment: I know that, by quotient test, when $c>e$ the series is divergent. But does it follow from it that the sequence (general term) itself diverges?

Comment: @amator2357, the quotient test says *more*, namely... (see previous comment). Quotient/ratio tests are a hidden comparison with a geometric series.

Comment: Thank you again and sorry for bombarding you with all those questions :)